# Salesforce.com configuration review tool

Tags: configuration

This is regarding quality control for Salesforce.com projects.  For Force.com development (custom coding), we have at least Source code security scanner which does static code analysis to some extent.  Do we have any other tools/utility for reviewing Salesforce.com configuration.  Whilst I understand that configuration is based on the requirements, there should be some sort of review against standard Salesforce.com configuration benchmarks/guidelines.

I have seen different solutions being offered for configuration review, most of them based on ISO 25010.

Has anyone used any tool/application for Salesforce.com configuration review?  Appreciate any inputs in this regard.

Answer (score -1):

One nice tool for configuration reporting is Cloud Converter by Model Metrics - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016cVIEAY

Another nice tool is Snapshot from Dreamfactory - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YhyEAE
it is a paid app, but you can do a lot with the free 14-day trial.